# Was the Spartan by Mimic Systems a real product?

Tags: commodore-64, apple-ii

I was flipping through an old copy of RUN magazine and came across an advertisement for a product called "The Spartan" produced by Mimic Systems.  I had forgotten about this product completely, but I remember lusting after one when I was in high school.

Here is a copy of the advert:

[image]

All these years later, I have to wonder if this product really ever existed or if it was just vaporware?  I have never seen an actual Spartan in real life.  I have never seen one on any auction site I track.  Frankly, if it really exists, I want one for my collection!

Does anyone have any first hand experience with this device?  Did it actually exist, and if so, did it live up to it's claims?

Comment: I want to mee the ad exec that said "we should go with a mime".

Comment: Why is it so enormous?

Comment: @Wilson, probably to (a) set your monitor on top and (b) hold apple ][ expansion cards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears to have [really existed](https://dfarq.homeip.net/ode-to-the-spartan/). Here's [a page](http://mikenaberezny.com/hardware/c64-128/mimic-systems-spartan/) with a manual PDF and EPROM images, and [another](https://www.applefritter.com/node/229) with pictures and an account by the head of software development for the product.

From those pages, it seems to have sort of worked, since there was an Apple II clone in the box, but it was easy to mess up the disk drives, and it was never popular.

From the comments, people sighted them being sold off cheap, and there's at least one still running.

Comment: I can confirm actually seeing them in person, stacked up in a bin at a surplus store. I was tempted to get one, but I already had an Apple II clone I could use.

Comment: Wow, it's a shame you didn't buy the whole stack.  After snooping around on ebay, these things are ridiculously priced - if you can find one at all.

Comment: Yes, a friend owns one. He always teases me that his C64 can do everything my Apple II can do and has better graphics :))